# Parsing verbs as object

Tags: subordinate-clauses, objects, parsing, bare-infinitives, verbs-of-perception

How do you parse *run across the street* below?

> I saw him (run across the street).

Comment: I would describe "him run across the street" as a non-finite clause, with the infinitive "run" as its head.

Comment: @ColinFine Well, I'm not used to parsing using terms such as head. Is it possible to use traditional tools. Thanks CF.

Comment: Traditionally, **him** is the direct object of **saw**, and **run across the street** is what was observed of him, an infinitival clause complement expressing the nature of his action.  Compare *I heard her sing*. The pattern is `{perceive} {someone}{do something}`  *I watched them go.*  *I felt it pinch*.

Comment: @learner: the term 'head' is simple and quite useful. Here is a definition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)

Comment: It's a catenative construction where the subordinate infinitival clause "run across the street" is catenative complement of "saw". The intervening noun phrase "him" is the syntactic object of "saw" and the understood subject of the subordinate clause. Would you like a diagram of the sentence?